# Windows universal app isolated storage - How to save and retrieve data?

Tags: windows, storage, win-universal-app, universal

I have this isolated storage helper and I need to use it to save and retrieve data from my universal app.

I don't know where to begin from. Should I maybe make an app and incorporate the helper class into it?

Here is my class:

```
using System.IO;
//using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
public static class IsolatedStorageHelper
{
    public static T GetObject<T>(string key)

       
    {
         var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

    



        if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            string serializedObject = localSettings.Values[key].ToString();
            return Deserialize<T>(serializedObject);
        }

        return default(T);
    }

    public static void SaveObject<T>(string key, T objectToSave)
    {
        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        string serializedObject = Serialize(objectToSave);
        localSettings.Values[key] = serializedObject;
    }

    public static void DeleteObject(string key)
    {
        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        localSettings.Values.Remove(key);
    }

    private static string Serialize(object objectToSerialize)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, objectToSerialize);
            ms.Position = 0;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    private static T Deserialize<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString)))
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and put some more information what problems you have encountered and what are you looking for?

Comment: yes , in fact i need to create an app and make a crud for my entity 'person' without re-writing the whole code .So , i need to use the class  ' storage helper.cs' mentioned above . Now i'm stuck as i don't know how to use it and do i implement it into my project . I would really use an example using this class to develop an UWP. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

use static `SaveObject` method and supply the 'person' entity and a key. Retrieve it later using `GetObject`.

But I think in this scenario you should use database `sqlite` and `sqlite net` package to save the entity.